# Why can't copy and paste file?

Tags: permissions

I am login with the account name `debian7`.
An error occur : Permission denied  when to copy and paste file into the directory  /home/tom .

```
ls  -al  /home/tom
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 2 tom  tom  4096 Jul 30 21:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Aug  8 08:19 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tom  tom   220 Jul 30 21:24 .bash_logout
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tom  tom  3392 Jul 30 21:24 .bashrc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tom  tom   675 Jul 30 21:24 .profile
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tom  tom    12 Jul 30 21:26 test.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tom  tom   602 Jul 30 21:26 .viminfo
```

The account name debian7 has the privilege in my sudoers.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
debian7   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Why can't copy and paste file into the directory  /home/tom ?

Answer (score 2):

Having privileges in the sudoers file onlc configures the use of the `sudo` command. It does not let you configure to run commands with root elevation without using sudo.

So your user is **entitled** to do everything as root, but this is not being done automatically. The only user that can read and write everything still is root, and only root.

So you still need `sudo` in order to access files of another user.

---

Alternatively, add *debian7* to the group *tom*. As you have group write permissions set, you will then be able to read and write into the other user's home:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tom debian7
```